# Using plugin template on front end

Tags: plugin-development, templating

I'm working on a plugin called `modelselector` and I want to use a template stored in the plugin `templates` folder but it should be shown on the front-end of the website.

Currently the following direct URL works for me:
`actions/modelSelector/showSelection/40c86a9b-53ec-43f4-8e8b-7c77ee0a13f5`

I also set up a site route like so:
`'modelselector/(?P<selectionUid>[^\/]+)' => array('action' => 'modelSelector/showSelection')`

However when I go to: `modelselector/40c86a9b-53ec-43f4-8e8b-7c77ee0a13f5` I get the error: `Unable to find the template “modelselector/show”.`.

I did some research and found that I need to set the template mode using: `craft()->templates->setTemplateMode(TemplateMode::CP);`. But this doesn't seem to work for me. It still can't find the template when the TemplateMode is on `CP` or `Site`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I’m struggling with this too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using Craft 2 syntax. This should work in Craft 3:

```
$vars = ['foo' => 'bar']; // variables loaded into the template
$mode = 'cp'; // or "site"
$html = Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('path/to/template', $vars, $mode);
return $html;
```